# Which key-value pair and certificate do curl, browsers and mobile app use to make https calls?

Tags: security, ssl, https, tls1.2

I've learned that there is a tls handshake that takes place during the tcp connection setup, which involves exchange of public keys and tls certificate.

My question is where do programs like `curl`, our browsers and mobile apps get these keys from because if I'm not creating them on my computer or phone and there's nothing in the `.ssh` directory, where are they present? If I run `curl https://whatever` or open a https link in my browser or mobile app, do they generate them themselves or are they provided by the OS? and if so, where are they placed?

I'm sorry if there are some gaps in my understanding of this, I'm new to this stuff. Kindly correct me if it as needed.

Comment: None. The *server* has the keypair. The client doesn't need one unless the server asks for it.

Comment: @user207421 ok, so client only generates it in cases where we must explicitly specify a certificate to the server to prove our identity? is that right?

Comment: No, the client already has a keypair and certificate in those cases. Generating a keypair and certificate on the fly doesn't prove anything.